# Why is UI output different between this XAML C# code version?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to determine why does the following C# code not result in the same output as the XAML version (Top picture is XAML, bottom picture is the code behind). All the parameters have equal values and I've nested my stacklayouts, and I'm not sure what is missing to equate the two outputs. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

The following is the XAML code:

```xml
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="8" Spacing="12" x:Name="JitPageStackView">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#3d4f7c" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Start">
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Frame HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="#ededef" Padding="6">
                <Label TextColor="Black"  Text="This is text"></Label>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

And this is the code behind:

```cs
var Description = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, Padding = new Thickness(6, 6, 6, 6), BackgroundColor = Color.White };
var Frame = new Frame { Content = new Label { Text = "This is a long text", TextColor = Color.Black }, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("ededef"), CornerRadius = 0 };
Description.Children.Add(Frame);
var Step = new StackLayout {WidthRequest = 50, HeightRequest=50, VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start, BackgroundColor=Color.FromHex("3d4f7c") };
var StepDisplay = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0, Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal };
StepDisplay.Children.Add(Step);
StepDisplay.Children.Add(Description);
JitPageStackView.Children.Add(StepDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C# version you are setting the padding to the `StackLayout` **"Description"** instead of the `Frame`

Change this and it should work as the XAML version

```
var Description = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, BackgroundColor = Color.White };
var Frame = new Frame { Content = new Label { Text = "This is a long text", TextColor = Color.Black }, BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("ededef"), CornerRadius = 0,  Padding = new Thickness(6, 6, 6, 6) };
Description.Children.Add(Frame);

var Step = new StackLayout {WidthRequest = 50, HeightRequest=50, VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start, BackgroundColor=Color.FromHex("3d4f7c") };

var StepDisplay = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0, Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal };

StepDisplay.Children.Add(Step);
StepDisplay.Children.Add(Description);
JitPageStackView.Children.Add(StepDisplay);
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Much appreciated!